Balancing Lecture Time and Engagement with Financial Law Students: Seeking Advice
I'm currently facing a challenge in teaching financial law to apprentices. I have limited classroom time with my students and need to cover a substantial amount of material. To address this, I’ve prepared detailed scripts for my slides and lectures. However, rather than simply conveying all the content in a breadth as opposed to depth, my goal is to provide examples on specific laws that encourage students to critically engage with the laws that they are reading, hence building their motivation when they read the book indpendently rather than just cover every aspect in depth.
I know that some of you may suggest recording videos of my lectures for students to watch in their own time. However, there are two reasons why I’ve hesitated with this approach:

Reading is Crucial: For my students, reading the book is more valuable and versatile. I see my role as providing specific examples and clarifications, not necessarily going over every detail of the material. Going in a depth for each law is going to take way more time than the expected allocated time for teaching.
Limited Study Time: My students are apprentices who have only one day a week dedicated to study from their employer. I prefer that they spend this time reading rather than watching videos, as I believe this will be more beneficial in preparing them for their professional exams (specifically, the CISI exam). Also, based on a survey, it seems evident to me that students like to listen to me speaking and discussing particular concepts as opposed to spend all the time solving questions similar to the CISI. So, this to me implies that I need to do a balance.

That said, students have expressed a preference for a teaching structure where I spend the first hour lecturing and the second hour solving problems similar to those they will encounter in their exams. I’m now considering recording a lecture video to show during the first hour of class, allowing me to pause the video to address questions as they arise and provide deeper insights into specific points. This video could also be made available after class for further review.
My concern is whether students will find this approach engaging or if they might prefer a live lecture (all online remember) where I speak directly to them. Has anyone implemented something similar, or do you have advice or recommendations on how to best balance lecture time, student engagement, and exam preparation?

What do you expect of them when they aren't in the "classroom"? How much time? How much effort? (Classroom being virtual, of course.)

@Buffy Sorry, I did not fully understand your comment. I am expecting them to read the textbook when they aren't in classroom. Around 3-4 hours of reading time with some MCQs activities. Yes, the classroom is virtual, not in-person, and students tend to not show cameras or interact unless you put explicit questions addressing them personally. which I find annoying as I want them to be active.

Do they have assignments that are graded? The formal interaction time is X hours. Is that all the time they are expected to devote?

Hello @Buffy, yes they do, formal interaction is about 3 hours every week for 8 weeks. No, they have to devote at least 3 to 4 hours extra each week for 8 weeks. But, how is this relavant?
